# unchecked call to TableRowSorter(M) as a member of the raw type TableRowSorter Java

Tags: java, tablerowsorter

He creado una tabla para ingresar los datos de clientes pero al hacer un `Clean and build` del proyecto me salen **warnings** referentes al `TableRowSorter`.

¿Cuál es el problema de que aparezcan esos **warnings**?

**Warnings:**

```
Listado_clientes.java:88: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to TableRowSorter(M) as a member of the raw type TableRowSorter
            TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends TableModel declared in class TableRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method setRowSorter in class JTable is applied to given types
            tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found: TableRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found:    TableRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:547: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setRowFilter(RowFilter<? super M,? super I>) as a member of the raw type DefaultRowSorter
        TRSFiltro.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textfield_buscar.getText(), columna));
  where M,I are type-variables:
    M extends Object declared in class DefaultRowSorter
    I extends Object declared in class DefaultRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:559: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to TableRowSorter(M) as a member of the raw type TableRowSorter
        TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter(tabla_clientes.getModel());
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends TableModel declared in class TableRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:560: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method setRowSorter in class JTable is applied to given types
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found: TableRowSorter
Listado_clientes.java:560: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found:    TableRowSorter
```

**Os muestro las líneas de los errores:**

```
private TableRowSorter TRSFiltro;

DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

//Ordenar las filas por la primera columna DNI.
TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);

public void filtrar_dni() {
   int columna = 0; //Es la fila del DNI.
   TRSFiltro.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textfield_buscar.getText(), columna));
}

private void textfield_buscarKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
    textfield_buscar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e){
       String texto = (textfield_buscar.getText());
       textfield_buscar.setText(texto);
       filtrar_dni();
    }
    });

    TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter(tabla_clientes.getModel());
    tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
}
```

Comment: Intenta con  `TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(modelo);`

Comment: Me siguen apareciendo los errores. Ya lo había probado.

Comment: ¿Cuál sería una posible solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La advertencia misma te dice que está pasando:

> unchecked call to _ as a member of the raw type _

Eso significa que estás usando una clase que fue programada con soporte para tipos genéricos sin especificarle ningún tipo de dato.

Suele pasar mucho cuando los novatos empiezan a usar `List` y sus implementaciones, simplemente no le ponen parámetros.

Para deshacerte de este síntoma lo mejor es especificarle el tipo de dato de acuerdo a tu versión de Java.

### Java <=7

Se debe especificar el tipo en ambos lados, si te falta en el lado izquierdo obtendrás exactamente la misma advertencia debido al *type erasure*.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

### Java 8

Se puede omitir el tipo mediante aserción diamante

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Java 9+

Se puede inferir el tipo mediante el uso de `var` (o inferencia diamante, lo que prefieras)

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Lo mismo aplica para tu clase

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
```

Al pasarle la interfaz estás pasándole el contrato, si bien no es la implementación `DefaultTableModel`, te permitirá desacoplar tu implementación de modelo en caso de que la quieras cambiar después sin romper el contrato.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y explicación. Me sirvió de bastante ayuda.